# Simple-Modal Alternative

Tags: css, modal-dialog

I use simple-modal to programatically call a lightbox( like : function( "image url.png" ); ) but the css is affecting my website stylesheet.

There is another alternative for this ?

Answer (score 0):

You should really post some code to get a proper answer.

A strategy that would help avoiding such a 'conflict' is to import your own custom CSS after any imported libraries. There may still be situations where the imported library takes precedence due to higher "specificality" of the CSS rule.

If you use Chrome, you can right click and choose "inspect element" to show the CSS rules that take precedence.